# Experience Editor overwriting items edited elsewhere

Tags: experience-editor, content-management

I have an interesting problem.  On my home page I have multiple controls that link to items (articles).  The controls are in the Final Rendering of the home page and the data source for the control is set to an article item.  I use `RenderingContext.Current.ContextItem` to access the item and pull info from the fields contained therein.  I have fields used specifically for the home page.

My problem is that we have **User A** who is editing the home page in Experience Editor.  **User B** edits one of the items that is linked from the home page.  **User B** locks & edits the item and then saves & unlocks the item.  **User A** then changes something OTHER THAN **User B's** item and when he saves the home page it will overwrite **User B's** changes without warning.  If **User A** edits the same item as **User B** then he will get a warning.

We are in a fast-paced, deadline environment so **User A** cannot edit the home page exclusively while other users stop working.

One possible solution is that there is an "in-between layer" of items that contain the information necessary for the home page and have links to the items defined in it (see sample template fields below).  But I don't know how to do something like that in Experience Editor.  This would put a layer of separation in-between the article items and the home page so that our home page user cannot overwrite the other editor's changes.

```
Data
    Headline:
    Blurb:
    Link to story:
```

[image: How the components are setup on the home page currently]

Comment: Kevin what version of Sitecore are you on?

Comment: Sitecore 8.2U6.